# How to filter results on a page built in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a bunch of artworks. I want to be able show only those artworks which are sold (which is a column in my table, :availability='Private collection'). How would I do this? This is what I've tried so far:
Create a 'sold' action in the artworks_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    if params[:tag] 
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    elsif params[:series]
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:series])
    elsif params[:availability]
      @artworks = Artwork.where(availability: 'Private collection')
    else
      @artworks = Artwork.all
    end
  end

  def sold
    @artworks = Artwork.where(availability: 'Private collection')
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
get 'sold' => 'artworks#index', :as => 'sold'
```

I know that I have artworks tagged as these separate options and they're showing up correctly on my show page (this is my form):

```
<%= f.input :availability, :collection => ['Available for purchase','Private collection','Not for sale'],  :as => :radio_buttons %>
```

All this doesn't seem to break anything, but neither does it allow me to see only those artworks which are sold when I got to http://localhost:3000/sold. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently routes to the articles index:

```
get 'sold' => 'artworks#index', :as => 'sold'
```

As a result it's using your query in the index action, and with no params it gets all of them.  So you need to route it to the sold action:

```
get 'sold' => 'artworks#sold', :as => 'sold'
```

Then in your controller you can tell rails to render the index view

```
def sold
  @artworks = Artwork.where(availability: 'Private collection')
  render :index
end
```

Which will use the index view but with the query from the sold action.

Comment: That was reeeally helpful. Thank you!